# Error jQuery(domChunk).live is not a function

Tags: plugins, jquery

I'm getting this error in FireFox:

```
Error: jQuery(domChunk).live is not a function Source File: http://www.bradford.nhs.uk/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.js?ver=3.1-20110528 Line: 26
```

This is the function:

```
//add thickbox to href & area elements that have a class of .thickbox
function tb_init(domChunk){
    jQuery(domChunk).live('click', tb_click);
}
```

Thickbox seems to be a build in WordPress feature but the theme we are using uses prettyPhoto.

Comment: I have changed this to .bind but it has caused other errors such as

Comment: Error: element.dispatchEvent is not a function
Source File: http ... www......uk /wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load=jquery,prototype,utils,scriptaculous-root,scriptaculous-builder,scriptaculous-effects,scriptaculous-dragdrop,scriptaculous-slider,scriptaculous-controls&ver=496be2cb050e55197c680d4612290054

Comment: Any plugins that re-register jQuery, from the sounds of it, something is registering an older version of jQuery, which does not support have the live function.

Comment: Correct - the version showing is 1.2.6 in the thickbox.js but the actual version I am loading is 1.6.1

Comment: Is jQuery only loaded once, ie. if you check the source of the page is there only 1.6.1, or are you seeing any other versions output? Any possibility of seeing a page with the problem?

Comment: Site is http://www.bradford.nhs.uk/

Comment: I do not get any errors on your site, error console is totally empty, did you change/remove something? Tested logged out? Tested another browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used jQuery(domChunk).bind
instead. This seems to work.